# "IndexError: list index out of range" Error in Python simulation

Tags: python, list, simulation

I'm currently developing a simulation in Python to model the movement of agents in a given environment. However, I'm encountering an "IndexError: list index out of range" error that I'm unable to resolve.

**Context:** I have to simulate the movement of multiple agents in a crowd, taking into account social repulsion forces, collision forces with walls, and an attractive force towards a specific point. I used Helbing's equation (which is the fundamental principle of dynamics applied to people, modeled by hard spheres, taking "social forces" into account). I used a discrete model to solve the equation numerically.

**Problem:** When I run the simulation with a certain number of agents and a maximum duration, I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" error. I've checked my code and identified that the error occurs when constructing the `li_lx` and `li_ly` lists from the simulation data. Sometimes it occurs when defining `Dij` in the `simulation` function.

**Code:**

```
    import numpy as np

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    import random

    

    k = 10

    wall_repulsion = 10

    # wall collision

    F0 = 4

    lambda0 = 1/3

    tau = 8

    delta = 2

    kappa = 300

    r = 0.15  # radius: 15 cm in reality <-> 1 in the simulation

    m = 80

    infinity = 10000000000000000

    etai_max = 0.3

    nu = 1  # fluid friction

    

    # TO BE COMPLETED.................................................

    xmin = 0

    xmax = 40

    # xmax = 1

    ymin = 0

    ymax = 20

    # ymax = 1

    exit_width = 0.5  # even

    exit_height = 0.5

    epsilon = 0.001

    

    # AUTOMATIC.................................................

    xmiddle = (xmax - xmin) / 2

    ymiddle = (ymax - ymin) / 2

    exit_xmin = xmilieu - (exit_width / 2)

    exit_xmax = ymilieu - (exit_width / 2)

    exit_ymin = ymax - exit_height

    exit_ymax = ymax_attrac = xmiddle

    y_attrac = ymax

    

    def distance(coord1, coord2):

        x1, y1 = coord1

        x2, y2 = coord2

        return np.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2) - 2*r

    

    def cos_phi(agent, other, t):  # t is the time when we ADD a value: so we take the last value : t - 1

        ex = (agent[t - 1][0] - other[t - 1][0]) / distance(agent[t - 1], other[t - 1])

        ey = (agent[t - 1][1] - other[t - 1][1]) / distance(agent[t - 1], other[t - 1])

        delta_x, delta_y = agent[t - 1][0] - agent[t - 2][0], agent[t - 1][1] - agent[t - 2][1]

        num = delta_x * ex + delta_y * ey

        den = distance(agent[t - 1], other[t - 1]) * np.sqrt(delta_x**2 + delta_y**2)

        return num / den

    

    def simulation(n, tmax):

        # posmat = [[[xmin + (i+1)*xmax/(n+1), ymax/4]]*2 for i in range(n)] 

        # Distributed uniformly in a line

        posmat = [[[random.uniform(xmin + 0.5, xmax - 0.5), random.uniform(ymin + 0.5, ymax - 0.5)]]*2 for i in range(n)]

        # print(posmat, 'initial')

        for t in range(2, tmax):

            for agent_index in range(n):

                if (exit_xmin <= posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] <= exit_xmax and matpos[agent_index][t - 1][1] >= exit_ymin) or (posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0], posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0]) == (infinity, infinity):

                    new_x, new_y = infinity, infinity

                else:

                # calculating repulsion forces (social repulsion, collision repulsion, wall repulsion)

                    social_force_x = 0

                    collision_force_x = 0

                    social_force_y = 0

                    collision_force_y = 0

                    for other_index in range(n):

                        if other_index != agent_index:

                            Dij = distance(posmat[agent_index][t - 1], posmat[other_index][t - 1])

                            ex = (posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - posmat[other_index][t - 1][0]) / abs(Dij)

                            ey = (posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1] - posmat[other_index][t - 1][1]) / abs(Dij)

                            if posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][0] != 0 and posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][1] != 0 and Dij != 0:

                                social_force_x += -F0 * np.exp(-Dij / delta) * (lambda0 + (1 - lambda0) * (1 + cos_phi(posmat[agent_index], posmat[other_index], t)) / 2) * ex

                                social_force_y += -F0 * np.exp(-Dij / delta) * (lambda0 + (1 - lambda0) * (1 + cos_phi(posmat[agent_index], posmat[other_index], t)) / 2) * ey

                           if Dij <= 0:

                               collision_force_x += kappa * Dij * ex

                               collision_force_y += kappa * Dij * ey

                   wall_repulsion_x = wall_repulsion / ((posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - xmin)**2) # left wall

                   wall_repulsion_x += wall_repulsion / ((xmax - posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0])**2)  # right wall

                   wall_repulsion_y = wall_repulsion / ((posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - ymin)**2)  # bottom wall

                   wall_repulsion_y += wall_repulsion / ((ymax - posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1])**2)  # top wall

                   # calculating eta_i

                   etax = random.uniform(-etai_max, etai_max)

                   etay = random.uniform(-etai_max, etai_max)

                   # calculating attraction Ui-Vi

                   ui_x = x_attrac - posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0]

                   vi_x = posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][0]

                   ui_y = y_attrac - posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1]

                   vi_y = posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][1]

                   new_x = 2 * posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][0] + 1 / tau * (ui_x - vi_x) + 1 / m * (social_force_x + collision_force_x + wall_repulsion_x) + etax - nu * vi_x  # FPD along ux

                   new_y = 2 * posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1] - posmat[agent_index][t - 2][1] + 1 / tau * (ui_y - vi_y) + 1 / m * (social_force_y + collision_force_y + wall_repulsion_y) + etay - nu * vi_y  # FPD along uy

               if new_x > xmax and ymin <= new_y <= ymax:

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmax - epsilon, new_y])

               if new_x < xmin and ymin <= new_y <= ymax:

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmin + epsilon, new_y])

               if xmin <= new_x <= xmax and new_y > ymax:

                   posmat[agent_index].append([new_x, ymax - epsilon])

               if xmin <= new_x <= xmax and new_y < ymin:

                   posmat[agent_index].append([new_x, ymin + epsilon])

               if new_x > xmax and new_y > ymax and (new_x, new_y) != (infini, infini):

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmax - epsilon, ymax - epsilon])

               if new_x > xmax and new_y < ymin:

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmax - epsilon, ymin + epsilon])

               if new_x < xmin and new_y > ymax and (new_x, new_y):

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmin + epsilon, ymax - epsilon])

               if new_x < xmin and new_y > ymin and (new_x, new_y):

                   posmat[agent_index].append([xmin + epsilon, ymin + epsilon])

               if xmin <= new_x <= xmax and ymin <= new_y <= ymax or (new_x, new_y) == (infini, infini):

                   posmat[agent_index].append([new_x, new_y])

        return posmat

    n = 100

    t0 = 20

    color_pallet = plt.get_cmap('tab20')

    li_ecolor = [color_pallet(k) for k in range(n)]

    # li_ecolor = ['b', 'g', 'y', 'c', 'm', 'k', 'orange', 'slateblue']

    sol = simulation(n, t0)

    li_lx = [[] for i in range(n)]

    li_ly = [[] for i in range(n)]

    

    for agent_index in range(len(sol)):

        for t in range(len(sol[0])):

            li_lx[agent_index].append(sol[agent_index][t][0])

            li_ly[agent_index].append(sol[agent_index][t][1])

            # print(li_lx)

    

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 12))

    plt.xlim(xmin, xmax + 1)

    plt.ylim(ymin, ymax + 1)

    

    for agent_index in range(len(sol)):

        for t in range(len(sol[0])):

            cercle = plt.Circle((li_lx[agent_index][t], li_ly[agent_index][t]), r, fill=True,edgecolor=li_ecolor[agent_index], facecolor=li_ecolor[agent_index])

            ax.add_artist(cercle)

            ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((fin_xmin, fin_ymax), largeur_fin, hauteur_fin, edgecolor='r', facecolor='r'))

    plt.show()
```

**Full error message:**

```
    IndexError.  Traceback (most recent call last) 

    Input In [14], in <cell line: 122>() 

            119 li_ecolor = [color_pallet(k) for k in range(n)] 

            121 # li_ecolor = ['b', 'g', 'y', 'c', 'm', 'k', 'orange', 'slateblue'] 

     -->    122 sol = simulation(n, t0) 123 li_lx = [[] for i in range(n)] 124 li_ly = [[] for i in range(n)]

    

    Input In [14], in simulation(n, tmax) 

            70 for other_index in range(n):

            71     if other_index != agent_index:

       ---> 72         Dij = distance(posmat[agent_index][t - 1], posmat[other_index][t - 1])

            73         ex = (posmat[agent_index][t - 1][0] - posmat[other_index][t - 1][0]) / abs(Dij)

            74         ey = (posmat[agent_index][t - 1][1] - posmat[other_index][t - 1][1]) / abs(Dij)

    

    IndexError: list index out of range
```

**What I've tried:** I've tried debugging the code by adding print statements to check the index values, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact source of the error. I've also verified that the dimensions of the lists are correct and match those of the simulation, which seem to be the correct...

Apparently, the `append` is not always done, so there has to be some index for which `posmat[i][t-1]` is unmatched by all the `if`, at the end of the code... But where is it ?

**Question:** Can anyone help me understand why this "IndexError: list index out of range" error is occurring and how to resolve it? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance !

Comment: The exact source of error is explicit, either `posmat[agent_index][t - 1]` or `posmat[other_index][t - 1]` split each into mutliple lines and you'll find the wrong one

Comment: Actually, Jupyter highlights `posmat[other_index][t - 1]`, so that's the exact source. But I want to understand why there is an error at this exact line of the code and how it could be solved. For example, I've tried to initialize `posmat` like this:

Comment: ```
posmat = [[[random.uniform(xmin+0.5, xmax-0.5), random.uniform(ymin+0.5, ymax-0.5)]]*2 + [[0,0]]*(tmax -2) for i in range(n)]
```

Now I get the `ZeroDivisionError` when calculating `wall_repulsion_x` which confirms the observation that for some index there must be an unmatched case...

But I still don't understand which case is unmatched and how I could solve the issue... That has to be a very tiny detail!

Comment: never post code in comment [edit] your post instead

Comment: to debug do `print(posmat[agent_index])` then `print(posmat[agent_index][t - 1])` then `print(posmat[other_index])` then `print(posmat[other_index][t - 1])` then you'll know exactly which one fails

Answer (score 0):

The error is on this line:

```
Dij = distance(posmat[agent_index][t - 1], posmat[other_index][t - 1])
```

This line is inside of a `for other_index in range(n)` loop, which suggests the problem is that `other_index` has exceeded the bounds of `posmat`.

To find out the exact problem, you can add some print statements above that line of code.  Print these values:

- The length of `posmat`
- The value of `agent_index`
- The value of `other_index`
- The length of `posmat[agent_index]`
- The length of `posmat[other_index]`
- The value of `t-1`

One you know those, you will know the exact location of the error.

However, this doesn't necessarily tell you the **cause** of the error.

When you get an index out of bounds error, the cause is (usually) either that your loop index is **bigger** than you intended, or the list is **smaller** than you intended.  I can't tell you which of those is the case here.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll try this right now and come to you later